# Keeping observations with maximal value of two columns

Tags: sql, sas

I've got a table like:

```
ID Value1 Value2 ...
1  4      80
1  5      99
1  5      100
2  7      30
2  7      33
2  22     11
```

Now, I would like to keep all observations where for each ID and Value1 the value of Value2 is the highest, i.e. the outcome shall look like:

```
ID Value1 Value2 ...
1  4      80
1  5      100
2  7      33
2  22     11
```

Does anyone got any ideas?

Best

Answer (score 1):

Using Group By clause to achieve your result :

```
SELECT ID ,Value1 ,MAX(Value2)
FROM Your_Table 
GROUP BY ID ,Value1
```

Comment: Notice the 3 dots (...) after Value2

Answer (score 1):

If using SAS and want to avoid SQL, you could sort all your variables in descending order and use a by statement with the first.ID statement to take only the first value ( which after sorting will be the highest).

```
proc sort data = have;
  by ID descending Value1 descending Value2 ...
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by ID;
  if first.ID;
run;
```

Note: Depending on the size of your data this may not be the most efficient due to sorting multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ROW_NUMBER is supported

```
select      *

from       (select      t.*
                       ,row_number() over 
                            (partition by ID,Value1 order by Value2 desc) as rn

            from        my_table 
            ) t

where       rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Group By with Max function

```
SELECT ID,  VALUE1 , MAX(VALUE2) AS VALUE2
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID, VALUE1
```

Comment: (1) the groups are per ID + Value1  (2) Notice the 3 dots (...) after Value2

Answer (score 0):

Using group by and joining on a sub select gets you

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, value1, MAX(value2) AS value2
    FROM the_table    
    GROUP BY ID ,value1
) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  AND t1.value1 = t2.value1
  AND t1.value2 = t2.value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
        select ID ,value1,Value2 from
        ( select ID ,value1,Value2,row_number() over
         ( partition by ID,Value1 order by Value2 desc )as rnk
         from 
        #TableName
        )a where rnk =1
```

OR

```
             select ID ,Value1,max(Value2)from 
            #TableName
            group by ID ,Value1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a SAS version.  The `id` statement in `proc summary` will automatically return the maximum value.  The `class` statement is equivalent to `group by`.  The `drop` statement gets rid of the automatic variables (`_type_`,`_freq_`) create in the procedure.

```
data have;
input ID Value1 Value2;
datalines;
1  4      80
1  5      99
1  5      100
2  7      30
2  7      33
2  22     11
;
run;

proc summary data=have nway;
class id value1;
id value2;
output out=want (drop=_:);
run;
```